# Assert on the postgres count output using bash

Tags: bash, postgresql, psql

I would like to make an assertion the output of a postgres query using bash. Concretely, I am writing a bash job that counts the number of rows and if the count is not equal to zero, does something to raise alert.

```
$ psql MY_DATABASE -c "SELECT COUNT(*) WHERE foo=bar"
 count
-------
    0
(1 row)
```

In my script, I would like to assert that the output of above query is zero. However I am not sure where to begin because the output is not a number, but a formatted multi line string.

Is there an option in psql that makes it output a single number when counting, or could you think of any other approaches?

Comment: Try `psql -qAt`. See the man page for details.

Comment: @teppic thanks, it worked. could you post an answer so I can accept? I also did `COUNT=$(psql MY_DATABASE -c "SELECT COUNT(*) WHERE foo=bar" | sed -n 3p | xargs)`, but your solution is more reliable.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use temporary file to redirect the output and use it. Once your work is done, delete the temp file.

```
psql your_database -c "SELECT COUNT(*) as Count from table_a where c1=something"  -t >assert.tmp
line=$(head -n 1 assert.tmp)
if [ $line -ge 0 ]; then
    echo "greater then 0 and values is--"$line
fi
rm assert.tmp
```

Hope it works for you.